# Surveillance mechanism for Node.js services

Tags: node.js, web-services

I have an application that's dependent on several smaller independent services. E.g. the email service is responsible for sending emails, etc.

Now, what would be the best practice to make sure none of these services goes unresponsive or crashes silently?

Currently I have a surveillance service that checks all other services, to make sure they are up. But what if that service goes dead?

Do I create a surveillance service to check the surveillance service?
Doesn't seem like a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a process manager, a piece of software, or even better, an external service that manages your nodejs instances.

Examples at:

- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisor
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever